# Zero length BigInteger (Transforming string into bytes)

Tags: java, string, byte, biginteger, numberformatexception

I got a little problem, I got this lines of code:

```
for(int i = 0; i<splits.length; i++){
    if(splits[i].length() < 8){
        remainder = splits[i];
    }
    else if(splits[i].length() == 8){
        System.out.println("'"+splits[i]+"'");
        byte[] bval = new BigInteger(splits[i], 2).toByteArray();
        dos.write(bval);
    }
}
```

So the problem is on this line:

```
byte[] bval = new BigInteger(splits[i], 2).toByteArray();
```

Here is what the print returns:

```
'11111111'
'11111110'
'11111111'
'11111011'
'11111111'
'11111101'
'11111111'
'11111110'
'11111011'
'11111111'
'11111110'
```

So it just crashes for no apparent reason as 11111110 is there multiple times.

Why is that?

Comment: Since the given output isn't what you want: what do you want to be printed out?

Comment: What is your goal with this code?

Comment: also you code makes heavy use of `splits` without showing us what it is/what's in it. You probably want to add those details too

Comment: When you ask a vague question such as this, you need to provide a minimally functioning code. As it stands, it is not clear what you are asking and no possibility of guessing.